# Microsoft Graph api does not give birthday user information

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

In graph explorer the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=birthday` endpoint gives me the example profile birthday

but when I try it with my account I receive this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "37e1643d-0bfd-46a4-8b48-70a4922f2952",
            "date": "2017-12-29T21:33:16"
        }
    }
}
```

even though it returns my profile with the `/me` endpoint. I believe it has all the same scopes as the example and I checked all the `.read` scopes to make sure it had everything needed.

My birthday is in my profile and I am able to get my birthday from the deprecated live api with the `wl.birthday` scope but not the new graph api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. Looks like we need to update our documentation.  I filed [this doc issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2101) to track. Some `user` properties are only available for commercial (work or school) accounts (i.e. AAD based), through Microsoft Graph. Microsoft Graph, when signed in though a consumer account, has limited access to the same data that is exposed in the deprecated live API. I'll check if this particular item can be fixed.

Hope this helps,

Comment: We are in need to get birthday property. Is there any update that this is fixed or not?